# Extreme local points

Tags: functions

Function has two extreme local points for m=? :f(x)= mx^2+1-ln(1+x) ,where m is real.I tried with derivate and I end up with something like f'x=(2mx^2+2mx-1)/(x+1). I put the condition that 2mx^2+2mx-1 has 2 real roots so I obtain that m is somewhere between (-inf,-2) and (0,inf) but the answeer is m<-2

Comment: Is there some more information for the given function? Like the "locality" of the extrema? Whatever you have arrived at seems absolutely perfect!

Comment: the function is defined on -1,inf

Comment: You get the condition directly from here!

Answer (score 1):

from $$x+1>0$$ we get
$$-1/2+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2m}}>-1$$ which is true, and
$$-1/2-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2m}}>-1$$ which is equivalent to $$m<0$$ therefore we have $$m<-2$$

Comment: I'm sorry,I dont understand how you got to those conditions ,the second and the third

Comment: i have solved the equation $$mx^2+1-\frac{1}{1+x}=0$$ for $x$